# What does `+""` mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just found this piece of code (simplified) in a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/50069/files) in the Ruby on Rails GitHub repository:

```
def foo(string)
  return +"" if string.empty?

  # ...
end
```

And I wonder what the `+""` means?

What difference does the `+` prefix make to the returned empty string `""`? And what is the advantage of returning `+""` instead of just `""` or the `string` string, which is empty at that point in this example?

Answer (score 3):

`+''` ensures that the returned string is not frozen, no matter if string literals in the file are implicitly frozen, for example, by a `# frozen_string_literal: true` magic comment.

Quote from the docs about [`String#+@`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-2B-40):

> **`+string` → `new_string` or `self`**
>
> Returns `self` if `self` is not frozen.
>
> Otherwise returns `self.dup`, which is not frozen.

Examples:

```
''.frozen?     #=> false
(+'').frozen?  #=> false
```

But with implicitly frozen strings:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

''.frozen?     #=> true
(+'').frozen?  #=> false
```

On the same note, the author decided to not simply returning the empty `string` string, because it might be frozen. Returning `+''` ensures an unfrozen empty string to be returned no matter how the environment or the input looks like.

A mnemonic to remember is the Celsius temperature unit (`°C`). The freezing point of water is defined as `0°C`. Which means every value with a negative sign is below the freezing point and, therefore, frozen. Positive signed values are not frozen.

Comment: Worth noting that there is also `#-`

```
irb(main):001:0> "".frozen?
=> false
irb(main):002:0> (-"").frozen?
=> true
```

Comment: @Pascal `-` not only freezes the string, it also attempts to _deduplicate_ it, i.e. you will likely receive the very same object for identical string values which is great for reducing memory usage.